# NameError: name doohickey is not defined

Tags: python, django

I am having issues importing a function from a module I created into my code. I am getting an error stating that the function is not defined, despite importing the module into my file.

The error message:

```
something = doohickey()
NameError: name 'doohickey' is not defined
```

get_random_tweet.py

```
import twitter

api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='',
                  consumer_secret='',
                  access_token_secret='')

timeline = api.GetUserTimeline(screen_name='realDonaldTrump',
                               include_rts=False,
                               trim_user=True,
                               exclude_replies=True,
                               count=6)

def doohickey():
    pprint(timeline)
    return {'index': "<i> something </i>"}
```

My views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from hello.sampled_stream import okdood
import hello.get_random_tweet
from .models import Greeting

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
   # return HttpResponse('Hello from Python!')
   # okdood()
   something = doohickey()
   return render(request, "index.html")
```

I have also attempted the following:

```
 from django.shortcuts import render
 from django.http import HttpResponse
 from hello.sampled_stream import okdood
 from hello.get_random_tweet import doohickey
 from .models import Greeting

 # Create your views here.
 def index(request):
 # return HttpResponse('Hello from Python!')
 # okdood()
 something = doohickey()
 return render(request, "index.html")
```

Error message:

```
 something = doohickey()
 NameError: name 'doohickey' is not defined
```

and

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from hello.sampled_stream import okdood
import hello.get_random_tweet
from .models import Greeting

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
# return HttpResponse('Hello from Python!')
# okdood()
something = hello.get_random_tweet.doohickey()
return render(request, "index.html")
```

Error message:

```
 something = hello.get_random_tweet.doohickey()
 NameError: name 'doohickey' is not defined
```

Comment: You need to import the function from your `get_random_tweet` module.

Comment: I did that. Still the same error message.

Comment: How did you do that?

Comment: I'm guessing that's not the real API access credentials you've pasted into a public place? :/

If it is, you might want to remove them?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the issue is that you are not referring to the `doohickey` function as part of the `hello.get_random_tweet` namespace. You can do this in several ways:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from hello.sampled_stream import okdood
from hello.get_random_tweet import doohickey
from .models import Greeting

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
   # return HttpResponse('Hello from Python!')
   # okdood()
   something = doohickey()
   return render(request, "index.html")
```

or

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from hello.sampled_stream import okdood
import hello.get_random_tweet
from .models import Greeting

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
   # return HttpResponse('Hello from Python!')
   # okdood()
   something = hello.get_random_tweet.doohickey()
   return render(request, "index.html")
```

As your code is currently structured, you import the `hello.get_random_tweet` module, but when you refer to `doohickey` Python is looking for it in the local namespace. However, it should be looking for it in the `hello.get_random_tweet` namespace. You can either import the function and add it to the local namespace, as shown in the first snippet, or refer to the function in the imported module's namespace as shown in the second snippet.

Comment: I've tried both these options. Still does not work.

Comment: @user2353418 Please post your results with these options.

Comment: First option error message: //something = doohickey()     //NameError: name 'doohickey' is not defined

Comment: @user2353418 How are you importing `doohickey`?

Comment: Second option error message: something = get_random_tweet.doohickey()
NameError: name 'doohickey' is not defined

Comment: I'm doing as you suggested above.

Comment: @user2353418 The second option had an issue which I corrected.  Please edit your question and add the code used and the results for either of the above snippets.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202525/discussion-between-user2353418-and-james-mchugh).

Answer (score 0):

Might be a copy/paste error, but you're missing endquotes on a few lines here, and the closing bracket:

```
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='',
                  consumer_secret='',
                  access_token_secret=''
```

Should be:

```
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='',
                  consumer_secret=''
                  access_token_key=''
                  access_token_secret='')
```